# How to set width on Flutter SliverGrid

Tags: flutter, nestedscrollview, customscrollview

I'm trying display a slivergridview view and it just doesn't look good if it's always on full width especially on large screens

[image]

But CustomScrollView only accepts sliver widgets, which makes container & sizedbox unusable.
What is your workaround on this one?

Answer (score 5):

1. First, wrap your Scaffold body with LayoutBuilder
2. Wrap SliverGrid with SliverPadding and set the vertical and horizontal width

```dart
    SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 15,
      horizontal: max((constraints.maxWidth - 1200) / 2, 0) > 15 ? max((constraints.maxWidth - 1200) / 2, 0) : 15),
      sliver: SliverGrid( ...
```

Here's the result
[image]

Comment: Nice solution. `max((constraints.maxWidth - 1200) / 2, 15)` would do just fine.